# How to define a template function that only accepts a base class with parameter T of type its subclass?

Tags: c++

It is not specific to casting. My scenario is how to define a template function that only accepts a base class for parameter `T` of type subclass.

```
template<typename T> // T must be a subclass
T* DoSomething(<I don't know> parent) // parent must be a base class
{
    // here the specified subclass of type T is produced.
    // return object of type T which is a subclass.
}
```

A contrived usage:

```
Parent* p = new Child();
Child* c = DoSomething<Child>(p);
delete p;
```

Comment: Aren't you just looking for [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)?

Comment: But `dynamic_cast` is for doing such a cast and to verify if that cast was valid. It is not clear what else you are looking for.

Comment: @t.niese: I want to make my `CastChecked` only accept base class and return the specified subclass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way could be by using [`std::is_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) or `std::is_base_of_v` in combination with a `static_assert`:

```
template<typename Derived, typename Base>
Derived* CastChecked(Base* parent)
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Base,Derived>);

    return dynamic_cast<Derived*>(parent);
}
```

Comment: If I change the order as `template <typename Base, typename Derived>`, it no longer works. So order does matter.

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer Yes the order matters. That’s due to how template type deduction works. The compiler can determine `Base` based on function argument you pass but `Derived` can’t so `Derived` has to appear before `Base`.

Answer (score 5):

As you are not specifying a language version, I want to add the C++20 and beyond way is to use concepts. Your case is actually shown as an example [on cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints).

For your case

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

// concept
template <class D, class B>
concept Derived = std::is_base_of_v<B, D>;

template <typename D, typename B>
    requires Derived<D, B>
D* CastChecked(B* parent) {
    return dynamic_cast<D*>(parent);
}

struct Foo {};
struct Bar : Foo {};
struct Baz {};

int main() {
    auto foo{Foo{}};
    Bar* bar{&foo};

    auto const r1{CastChecked<Foo>(bar)};

    // auto const r2{CastChecked<Baz>(bar)}; fails
}
```

However, you don't have to roll your own concept, as there's already a concept in the standard library: [`std::derived_from`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/derived_from). So you can just write:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template <typename D, typename B>
    requires std::derived_from<D, B>
D* CastChecked(B* parent) {
    return dynamic_cast<D*>(parent);
}
```